# how to set "Textmode" to gridview Column dynamically On Basis Of HeaderName

Tags: asp.net

i want to set formatting "Textmode" to Dynamic GridView Column but i am getting 
this error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index" this error...

Here Is my code:-

```
 GridView dg = new GridView();
 dg.DataSource = dsInput.Tables[0];
 dg.DataBind();
 int index = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < dg.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
      string headerRowText = dg.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
      GridViewRow row = dg.Rows[i];
      if (headerRowText == "CPR or Medical Card No.")
      {
          index=i;
          row.Cells[index].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
      }
 }
```

Comment: You are trying to access a cell with the same index as the row? Are there as many columns in your gridview as there are rows? I doubt that. Hence the error that "there is no cell with this index"

Comment: actually i am trying to access a column by a header text and want to set a textmode dynamically to that column

Comment: The first line in the loop tries to access cell with index i. What will happen if you have 100 rows in the gridview and i = 99, you can't possibly have cell with index 99 (dg.HeaderRow.Cells[99]).